Formatting content with TanStack Table
I'm using TanStack Table and am attempting to implement a specific responsive layout. I'm attempting to make a stacked layout, similar to what Gmail does when the content is compacted.

As you can see, despite being a table, this spans multiple rows. I was able to implement this myself with the following code:
<div class="w-full @container">
  <table class="w-full">
    <tr class="bg-primary-foreground hover:bg-primary-foreground/60 flex w-full cursor-pointer select-none flex-col p-1 @md:flex-row" , className onClick="{onClick}">
      <td class="w-full flex-shrink-0 @md:w-3/12">
        <div class="flex w-full justify-between @md:block">
          <div class="w-full max-w-[200px] truncate">name</div>
          <div class="text-muted-foreground @md:hidden">timestamp</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="w-full max-w-[300px] flex-shrink-0 truncate @md:w-4/12">subject</td>
      <td class="text-muted-foreground flex-shrink flex-grow truncate">body text</td>
      <td class="hidden flex-shrink-0 justify-end @md:flex">timestamp</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

However, when migrating to use TanStack I'm stuck as to how I might re-implement this given the method of mapping over the tables cells.
My current implementation is:
<Table>
    {table.getRowModel().rows?.length ? (
    table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
        <tr key={row.id} data-state={row.getIsSelected() && "selected"}>
        {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
            <td key={cell.id}>{flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}</td>
        ))}
        </tr>
    ))
    ) : (
    <tr>
        <td colSpan={columns.length} className="h-24 text-center">
        No results.
        </td>
    </tr>
    )}
</table>

How can I adjust my TanStack implementation to match the formatting of the original implementation?
